# webview в lollipop

Tags: android, webview

Решил перевести программу на lollipop, столкнулся с таким поведением webview. На prelollipop осях выдает: `target host must not be null...` на 5+ пишет проблемы с загрузкой fonts и дальше что-то по access policy. Кто знает как правильно создать webview 5+, может settings какие прописать или `extraheaders` в `loadurl`?
Что я уже пробовал:

1. Прописать в :

   ```
   extraheaders Access-Control-Allow-Origin*
   Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
   responseHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
   webview.loadUrl(url, responseHeaders);
   ```
2. Добавить в :

   ```
   settings setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs
   ```

думаю уже о том, что может быть для девайса 5+ применять как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297168/webview-in-lollipop-doesnt-load-fonts-from-assets) написано

Comment: Это где такие ошибки? Покажите их полный текст и ваш код.

Comment: вписал кусок кода в вопрос, а ошибка такая: Font from origin 'http://some_site.ru' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dom.some_site.ru' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: вот самое гавное вы указали только в комментариях.  Попробуйте `loadDataWithBaseURL()` где в baseUrl укажите `dom.some_site.ru`

Comment: так а в data мне что вписать? мне надо получить исх. html страницы с выполненными js